# Assigning values as new column based on percentages from another table

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have two tables one is a row-level table another is a corresponding table with variables.

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Output Required -

[image]

The variable should be populated in a new column based on the % of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use symbols as field names; user the word `percentage` rather than the symbol `%`.

Second, your mapping table *(`table2`)* should probably have the lower and upper bounds to make things simpler later on...  *(You can accomplish that using window functions if you can't correct the mapping table.)*

Then you can use window functions on your data to identify each row in terms of which row it is within just its own group.

Once done, it becomes a relatively simple join...

```
WITH
  map AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(percentage) OVER (PARTITION BY State, Region ORDER BY Variable)  AS upper_bound
  FROM
    Table2  # lower_bound is just upper_bound - percentage
),
  data AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY State, Region) - 1  AS group_row_number,   # -1 to make the row number start from zero
    COUNT(*)     OVER (PARTITION BY State, Region)      AS group_size
  FROM
    Table1
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  data
INNER JOIN
  map
    ON  data.Region = map.Region
    AND data.State  = map.State
    AND data.group_row_number >= data.group_size * (map.upper_bound - map.percentage)
    AND data.group_row_number <  data.group_size *  map.upper_bound
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

- **Version 1**

Non-orthodox version with use of [RANGE_BUCKET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#range_bucket) function

```
#standardSQL
WITH buckets AS (
  SELECT state, region, 
      ARRAY_AGG(variable ORDER BY variable) variables, 
      ARRAY_AGG(percentage ORDER BY variable) bins
  FROM (
    SELECT state, region, variable, SUM(1. * percentage) OVER(win) percentage
    FROM table2  
    WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY state, region ORDER BY variable)
  )  
  GROUP BY state, region
)
SELECT user, state, region, 
  variables[OFFSET(
    RANGE_BUCKET((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(win) - 1) / (COUNT(1) OVER(win)) * 100, bins)
  )] AS variable
FROM table1
JOIN buckets USING (state, region)
WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY state, region)
-- ORDER BY user
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row user    state   region  variable     
1   1       ORD     1       ABC  
2   2       ORD     1       ABC  
3   3       ORD     1       ABC  
4   4       ORD     1       XYZ  
5   5       ORD     1       XYZ  
6   6       ORD     1       XYZ  
7   7       IAD     2       ABC  
8   8       IAD     2       ABC  
9   9       IAD     2       ABC  
10  10      IAD     2       ABC  
11  11      IAD     2       AED  
12  12      IAD     2       AED  
13  13      IAD     2       XYZ  
14  14      IAD     2       XYZ
```

- **Version 2**

Below is more traditional version (obviously with same output as in above/first version)

```
#standardSQL
WITH buckets AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(percentage) OVER(PARTITION BY state, region ORDER BY variable) AS bin
  FROM table2  
), table1_with_stats AS (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(win) - 1 AS position, 
    COUNT(*) OVER(win) AS size
  FROM table1
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY state, region)
)
SELECT user, state, region, variable
FROM table1_with_stats
INNER JOIN buckets
USING (state, region)
WHERE position BETWEEN size * (bin - percentage) / 100
  AND size * bin /100 - 1
-- ORDER BY user
```

- **Test Data**

You can test, play with above using below CTE

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 1 user, 'ORD' state, 1 region UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ORD', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'ORD', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'ORD', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'ORD', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'ORD', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'IAD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'IAD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'IAD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'IAD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'IAD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'IAD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 'IAD', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'IAD', 2 
), table2 AS (
  SELECT 'ORD' state, 1 region, 'ABC' variable, 50 percentage UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ORD', 1, 'XYZ', 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'IAD', 2, 'ABC', 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'IAD', 2, 'XYZ', 25 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'IAD', 2, 'AED', 25 
)
```